# WPF Label does not update Data When Data changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When I change **Room** in **RoomViewModel** and **OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Room));** but Label binding **Room.NameRoom** doesn't update. Data Room was changed.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Anyone can help me?

In advanced, thanks so much.

RoomViewModel

```
using Learning.Core;
using Learning.EventRegister;
using Learning.MVVM.Model;
using Prism.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Learning.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class RoomViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public List<Item> items { get; }

        private Room room;
        private string nameRoom;

        public RoomViewModel()
        {
            room = new Room("1", false);
            nameRoom = room.NameRoom;
            items = new List<Item>();
        }

        public Room Room
        {
            get => room; set
            {
                room = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Room));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RoomView.xaml **<Label Content="{Binding Room.NameRoom}"**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Learning.MVVM.View.RoomView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Learning.MVVM.View"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Learning.MVVM.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:RoomViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Room.NameRoom}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Foreground="White"/>
        <Border Background="#cbc531" 
                Padding="10"
                Margin="10"
                CornerRadius="10">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="Giờ đến: "
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Content="12:29 AM"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Content="Thời gian hát: "
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Content="10 phút"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Button Background="Transparent"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            Padding="0"
                            Width="50"
                            Height="50"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image Source="../../Images/invoice.png"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <ListView 
              Background="Transparent"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemInRoom}"
            >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>

        <Border Background="#cbc531" 
                Padding="10"
                Margin="10"
                CornerRadius="10">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="Tạm tính: "
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Content="200000"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Content="Khoản thu khác: "
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Content="10000"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Content="Tổng tiền: "
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Content="210000"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Button Background="Transparent"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            Padding="0"
                            Width="50"
                            Height="50"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image Source="../../Images/invoice.png"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Room.cs

```
using Learning.Core;
using Learning.MVVM.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Learning.MVVM.Model
{
    public class Room : ObservableObject
    {
        private string name;
        private bool isActive;

        public Room(string name, bool isActive) { 
            this.name = name;
            this.isActive = isActive;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NameRoom));
            }
        }
        public bool IsActive { get => isActive; set
            {
                isActive = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorRoom));
            }
        }

        public string ColorRoom
        {
            get
            {
                if (isActive )
                {
                    return "#ffce00";
                }else
                {
                    return "White";
                }
            }
        }

        public string NameRoom
        {
            get
            {
                return $"Phòng {name} - Lầu 1";
            }
        }

        public object This
        {
            get => this;
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel

```
using Learning.Core;
using Learning.EventRegister;
using Learning.MVVM.Model;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Learning.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public RelayCommand HomeViewConmmand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand DiscoveryViewConmmand { get; set; }

        public HomeViewModel HomeVM { get; set; }
        public DiscoveryViewModel DiscoveryVM { get; set; }
        public RoomViewModel RoomVM { get; set; }

        private object _currentView;
        private object _rightView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public object RightView
        {
            get { return _rightView; }
            set
            {
                _rightView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        EventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
            HomeVM = new HomeViewModel(_eventAggregator);
            DiscoveryVM = new DiscoveryViewModel();
            RoomVM = new RoomViewModel();

            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CommandSendEvent>().Subscribe(GetRoom);

            CurrentView = HomeVM;
            RightView = RoomVM;

            HomeViewConmmand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = HomeVM;
            });

            DiscoveryViewConmmand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = DiscoveryVM;
            });
        }

        private void GetRoom(Room cur_room)
        {
            RoomVM.Room = cur_room;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the `RoomView` since you are creating a (the?) `RoomViewModel` in the `MainViewModel`:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:RoomViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Setting the `Room` property of the `RoomViewModel` that you create in the `MainViewModel` won't affect the other instance that you create in the markup of the `RoomView`. There should only be one instance of `RoomViewModel`.